# DBEngine Variable not defined in vb 6.0

Tags: ms-access, vb6, vbscript, ms-access-2003

when i write dbengine.Workspace("", "", "")
it shows error near dbengine variable not defined.

Comment: Is this VB6? Or VBScript? Or even VBA (Access macros)?

Answer (score 1):

Have you added a reference to [DAO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266542%28v=VS.60%29.aspx)? [DBEngine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb177488%28v=office.12%29.aspx) is part of DAO

In VB6 choose menu option `Project-References` and tick `Microsoft DAO 3.6 Object Library`

[image]